# "Escapar" string de arquivo carregado externamente

Tags: regex, query, actionscript-3, syntax-error

### Problema:

Estou tentando passar para o banco de dados uma String contendo os bytes de uma imagem que foi carregada externamente para colocar em um campo BLOB. Como sempre ocorre, os bytes da imagem  possui *aspas simples* `'`, *aspas duplas* `"` e *barra invertida* `\`. Acontece que a barra invertida é um *metacaractere* e as aspas são delimitadores de uma String literal, e é aí que surgem os problemas. Vejam o **exemplo** de bytes:

> "ÍäWÓužü’vaŽyt¾'m&²2\

Ao carregar estes bytes na String, eu preciso que eles fiquem *"escapados"*, assim:

> \"ÍäWÓužü’vaŽyt¾\'m&²2\\

Se eu tento carregá-los dentro do objeto `ByteArray` do Flash, os bytes são reconhecidos normalmente, mas para a comunicação com o banco de dados, é necessário que eles estejam em formato de `String`.

Abaixo um exemplo no código:

```js
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("URL_DA_IMAGEM"));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {

    var string:String = loader.content.loaderInfo.bytes.toString();
    var query:String = "INSERT INTO tabela (arquivo) VALUES (' "+string+" ')";
    var bytearray:ByteArray = loader.content.loaderInfo.bytes;

    trace(loader.content.loaderInfo.bytes); //"ÍäWÓužü’vaŽyt¾'m&²2\ - VALOR CORRETO, PORÉM NÃO ESCAPADOS
    trace(string); //"ÍäWÓužü’vaŽyt¾'m&²2\ - VALOR CORRETO, PORÉM NÃO ESCAPADOS
    trace(query); /*Erro pois a string com as aspas simples/aspas duplas não está escapada, 
    logo a query dá erro de syntax: INSERT INTO tabela (arquivo) VALUES (' "ÍäWÓužü’vaŽyt¾'m&²2\ ')
    */

}
```

### Tentativas:

1. Utilizar a String `query` passando como parâmetro o `ByteArray`. Mas obtive erro, pois ByteArray não é `String`.
2. Método `replace` com RegExp não funciona: `string.replace(/(\')/g, "\'");` pois o Flash remove automaticamente a barra invertida, e não a mantém.

### Pergunta:

Alguém possui uma solução?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um byte array não é uma string e não deve ser tratado como tal.

São apenas bytes, que se calham de virar um caractere com acento por mero acaso. Se você retirar o acento, mudará o formato dos bytes, e consequentemente o seu arquivo.

Eu não sei ActionScript, mas pelo que vi deve ser algo assim:

```
var query:SqlStatement = new SqlStatement();
query.text = "INSERT INTO tabela (arquivo) VALUES (:byteArray)";

query.parameters[":byteArray"] = loader.content.loaderInfo.bytes;
```

Comment: Infelizmente a conexão é com o MySQL e não SQL Local e estou utilizando o Flash Player, logo as classes do Adobe AIR são incompatíveis.

Comment: Entendi. Não há nenhum utilitário de conexão com o MySQL disponível que aceite SQL parametrizado?

Comment: Creio que não. O ActionScript em si não possui uma classe interna para conexões com o MySQL. A biblioteca que estou utilizando é a ASQL, uma antiga e descontinuada, porém funcional. Tentei utilizar o mesmo objeto do Flash (SQLStatement), mas não consigo passar parâmetros através dele.

Comment: O problema é, você não pode pegar um dado qualquer externo e salvar no seu banco sem tratamento. Sua aplicação fica sujeita a injeção de SQL. Imagine que alguém suba um arquivo contendo os bytes `39 41 59 32 68 82 79 80 32 84 65 66 76 69 32 70 73 76 69 83`. Ao fazer o toString, isso vira `'); DROP TABLE FILES`.

Comment: O que vc pode tentar fazer é converter cada byte pra int, depois para string. Ficará com uma representação parecida com essa acima. E te protege de injeção de SQL...

Comment: Entendi, a codificação para BASE64 me ajudou também, isso seria uma alternativa?

Comment: Acredito que seja seguro. Base64 aceita somente os caracteres `[a-zA-Z0-9+/]`.